# Calculating opening balance of a month using Mysql

Tags: mysql

Could someone explain the simplest method of calculating opening balance of a month using Mysql. For calculating opening balance I have month as input and debit amount and credit as table fields. I want to calculate opening balance up to a particular month.

```
TransactionId DebitAmount CreditAmount TransactionDate 
------------- ----------  ------------ ---------------- 
1             40000       500000    2015-12-07 
2             60000       700000    2015-12-08 
3             90000       800000    2015-12-11 
4              5000         3000    2015-12-11 
5             70000        90000    2015-12-11 

Input: Month : Jan 

Expected Output 
OpeningBalance 
-------------- 
Debit : SomeAmount 
Credit : SomeAmount
```

Comment: Provide more details

Comment: I have DebitAmount, CreditAmount and Date in my table. I want to calculate opening balance up to a selected month.

Comment: provide table structure and expected output with sample data.

Comment: TransactionId   DebitAmount     CreditAmount    TransactionDate
-------------   ----------- ------------    ----------------
1  40000  500000  2015-12-07
2  60000  700000  2015-12-08
3  90000  800000  2015-12-11
4  5000  3000  2015-12-11
5  70000  90000  2015-12-11

 
Input: Month : Jan

Expected Output

OpeningBalance 
--------------
Debit : SomeAmount

Credit : SomeAmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, if I am understanding correctly:

```
select 
  concat('Debit: ', sum(debitamount)) as 'Opening Balance'
from test 
where 
  month(transactiondate) = month( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) ) 
  and year(transactiondate) = year( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) )

union all

select 
  concat('Credit: ', sum(creditamount)) 
from test 
where 
  month(transactiondate) = month( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) ) 
  and year(transactiondate) = year( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) );
```

If your data looked like this:

```
+---------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| transactionid | debitamount | creditamount | transactiondate |
+---------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|             1 |         100 |          200 | 2015-12-05      |
|             2 |         200 |          400 | 2015-12-05      |
+---------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Result:

```
+-----------------+
| Opening Balance |
+-----------------+
| Debit: 300      |
| Credit: 600     |
+-----------------+
```

EDIT:

Based on the opening balance calculation here's the query

```
select 
  concat('Opening balance: ', sum(creditamount-debitamount)) as result
from test 
where 
  month(transactiondate) = month( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) ) 
  and year(transactiondate) = year( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) )

union all

select 
  concat('Debit: ', sum(debitamount)) 
from test 
where 
  month(transactiondate) = month( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) ) 
  and year(transactiondate) = year( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) )

union all

select 
  concat('Credit: ', sum(creditamount)) 
from test 
where 
  month(transactiondate) = month( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) ) 
  and year(transactiondate) = year( date_sub('2016-01-01', interval day('2016-01-01')+1 day) );
```

Result:

```
+----------------------+
| result               |
+----------------------+
| Opening balance: 300 |
| Debit: 300           |
| Credit: 600          |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I think the equation for calculating opening balance is capital=sum(creditedamount)-sum(debitedamount) and I if capital is +ve then opening balance is credit otherwise debit.

Comment: Update added based on your comment